# Checking Presence of element after parsing html in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to check if there is a element "TierRank unranked" in list below (named rank1)

```
<div class="TierRankInfo">
<div class="RankType">Ranked Solo</div>
<div class="TierRank unranked">
        Unranked
        </div>
</div>
```

So, i coded like this.

```
rank1 = soup.find("div", {"class": "TierRankInfo"})
if sum(["TierRank unranked" in x for x in rank1]) > 0:
    print("You are unranked")
else:
    print("You are ranked")
```

but every time i checked it says "You are ranked".... 
Did I do something wrong???

Comment: If you use findAll, you will get a list. You can then check the length of that list to determine if that element exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by:

```
html = """
<div class="TierRankInfo">
<div class="RankType">Ranked Solo</div>
<div class="TierRank unranked">
        Unranked
        </div>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print("You are unranked" if soup.findAll("div", {"class": "TierRank unranked"}) else "You are ranked")
```

That will print "You are unranked" if there is at least one div with "TierRank unranked" class else it will print "You are ranked"

Comment: Thx, problem Solved.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check the individual unranked tag, instead of a parent tag?

```
rank1 = soup.find("div", {"class": "TierRank unranked"})
if "Unranked" in rank1.text:
    print("You are unranked")
else:
    print("You are ranked")
```